# Unix: How can I check if 1 line has a space?

Tags: unix

`line="I have a space"`

It doesn't seem that I can `grep` this. `$line | grep "[[:space:]]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work, but you need to `echo` the line:

`echo "I have a space" | grep "[[:space:]]"`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $line | grep " "
```